# What is the dot product of a function and a differential?

Tags: notation

In a few theorems with integrals it looks like they are taking the dot product of a vector valued function or vector field and the differential.

$\oint_C \textbf{F} ⋅ d \textbf{r}$ from [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem#Relationship_to_the_Stokes_theorem)
and $\int_C \textbf{F}(\textbf{r})⋅d\textbf{r}$ [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Definition_2) for examples.

However, we are always given its simplified form so that we can compute it. Is it just written that way to give some indication of what is being calculated, or can this opertion be done if I do not know its simplified form?

Edit: by simplified I mean getting the integral to the point that you are no longer taking the dot product between a function and the differential.
For example $\int_C \textbf{F}(\textbf{r}) ⋅ d \textbf{r} = \int_a^b \textbf{F}(\textbf{r}(t)) ⋅ \textbf{r}'(t) dt$

Comment: What do you mean by "simplified form" ?

Comment: I added what I mean to the question. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that $\mathbf{F}:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$. Then
$$ \oint_C \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r}
= \oint_C \begin{bmatrix} \mathit{F}_0 \\\mathit{F}_1 \\\mathit{F}_2 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} dx \\ dy \\ dz \end{bmatrix}
= \oint_C (\mathit{F}_0 dx + \mathit{F}_1 dy + \mathit{F}_2 dz)
$$
It may be seen as a short hand for writing a sum, but does have mathematical meanings.

Comment: That makes more sense, but why does that result in r'(t) in the line integral?

Comment: @Corey Using the chain rule, $\frac{dr}{dt} dt = dr$

Answer (score 0):

$\oint_C \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r}$ is a shorthand notation for the following:

Let $\mathbf{F}:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ and $\textbf r:[0,1]\to \mathbb R^3$ be a parameterization of $C$ given by $t\mapsto (x(t),y(t),z(t))$.

Then, by definition the line integral of $\textbf F$ along $C$ is $\oint_C \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r}=\int_0^1\mathbf{F}(\textbf {r}(t))\cdot \textbf r'(t)dt$.

If we suppress the parameter $t$ in the above, we get

$\mathbf{F}((x,y,z))=(F_0,F_1,F_2)$ and $\textbf r'(t)dt=(dx,dy,dz)$ so that

$\oint_C \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}=\oint_C (F_0,F_1,F_2)\cdot (dx,dy,dz)=\oint_C F_0dx+F_1dy+F_2dz,\ $ which is how one usually writes these line integrals.